# Simple recursion base case

Tags: javascript, recursion

Why is this function returning undefined? I have seen cleaner and better ways to do this, and I understand it's generally bad practice to modify an array like this. Nonetheless, I am unclear as to why this example doesn't return 15. I've console-logged like crazy. Thank you in advance for your zen-like newbie-tolerance.

The steps as I see them:

- Pass in an array and give no second argument which defaults to 0
- Array value is popped and this is added to total
- Recursive call passing in the newly shortened array as well as the current total.
- When the length of the array equals zero, exit condition is met and the total is returned.

```js
var sumOfArray = function(array, total = 0) {
  var temp = 0;

  // base case
  if (array.length == 0) {
    return total;
  }

  temp += array.pop();
  total += temp;

  sumOfArray(array, total);
};


console.log('sumOfArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]=' + sumOfArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: You should *return*  the return value from the recursive call, otherwise you don't return anything (= undefined).

Comment: yes of course, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hey man mostly everything on that code was correct.  You were only missing a return statement in the else block and some other minor things; we have all been there.

```
var sumOfArray = function(array, total=0) { 
  var temp = 0;
  if (array.length === 0) { 
    return total;
  } else {
    temp += array.pop(); 
    total += temp;
    return sumOfArray(array, total);
  }
}

sumOfArray([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: Funny how obvious that looks now... thank you!